# Convert String to HTMLAgility Web Form

Tags: c#, forms, html-agility-pack

I have a string in C# which contains a complete HTML form. Now, I want to typecast it into a HTMLAgility Web Form. I am trying it for the last 12 hours now and will be very glad if someone help me out.

For Example,

This is a String:

```
String st = "<form>
                  First name:<br>
                  <input type="text" name="firstname">
                  <br>
                  Last name:<br>
                  <input type="text" name="lastname">
             </form>"
```

Now, the contents of the above string contains a complete form. What I want is that I want to extract that form, convert it into a valid HTML form and further use it like a form, not like the string.

Thanks

Comment: What exactly have you tried? Your question lacks any examples of code you've tried as well as description of problems you've faced.

Comment: I have edited the code. Please have a look. I hope it is a bit more explanatory now.

Comment: It is still not quite explanatory now. Surely you can use HTML Agility Pack to parse this string into couple of `HtmlNode` elements. But what do you mean by "further use it like a form"? Somehow show it like a browser does? That's not HtmlAgility Pack intended for. Or maybe post some data to the server like form does when being submitted? Again - HtmlAgility Pack is not a tool for this, you can do it easy using `HttmlWebRequest`. So what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to post data to the server like a normal form does when submitted.

Comment: As I've said - you can do it using `HttpWebRequest` class. Just create appropriate request and post it to the server.